# Creating resolvable URIs

Tags: uri, naming, jena

am using Jena, Java to generate RDF statements. I want to know if there are rules I need to follow to generate resolvable URIs.

Comment: What do you mean by 'resolvable URIs'?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about what is now referred to as *[linked data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data)*, and yes, there are [patterns you should follow](http://patterns.dataincubator.org/book/). At its simplest, you should (i) use `http:` URI's, (ii) ensure that those URI's refer to locations in a web space you control, and (iii) ensure that an HTTP GET request to those URI's, with an appropriate mime type, will result in machine-readable representations of the resources they denote.